# PHP error message smaller than normal

Tags: php, xdebug

Recently I was testing my PHP script and I got an error,but the Xdebug message was too small like I had it on 50% in browser. I barely could read anything unless I zoomed in to 150-200%.

So i'm asking is there some option to increase size of the error message?

I tried researching this,  but it seems like none ever issued thing.

EDIT:It adds `<font size="1">` before the error, anyone knows why?

Comment: It's probably due to the stylesheets of your page.

Comment: I don't have any stylesheet on my page.It seems like it adds <font size="1"> and idea why it adds that or is it possible to remove it without compiling the source again or downloading the php again?

Comment: Don't just guess "it seems like it adds `<font size="1">`. You can see the HTML in your browser. What exactly does it add? It will be much easier to debug once you know what you're trying to debug.

Comment: I said it adds <font size="1"> before the error message, but can't get used to this editor.Deleting the size="1" solves the problem temporarily,any guess for permanent solution.Anyway what is up with minuses?

Comment: I have the same problem, I have found that the default page font makes the text almost unreadable at that size, changing the font helped a lot eg. `font-family: Verdana`

Comment: Another solution is to create a debug style sheet that you can include on your development server, that way you can style the error messages any way you want, the output has the class `xdebug-error` so changing the style is very easy.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely due to a stylesheet of yours, or the browsers.